# Iterating over ArrayList sent from servlet on JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller, httpsession

I am sending the ArrayList from servlet to JSP, and I want to iterate over that ArrayList. But the problem is that I am getting that ArrayList from other class as below.

```
ArrayList<Integer> courseNumber= courseTable.getCN();
```

I am setting this arraylist in session attribute, and trying to iterate over that ArrayList in JSP. I have tried

> Foreach loop in JSP

But I am getting the result as below.

> [1421  1130  1132   1168]

I want to show the result as below

> 1421
>
> 1130
>
> 1132
>
> 1168

I don't know how to get that, I tried google, some udemy courses and all. Nothing is showing me right way. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, don't use session just for passing data between servlet and JSP. It's inefficient and is an overkill. Use request attributes instead.

```
request.setAttribute("courses", courseNumber);
```

Then in JSP do:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<c:forEach var="course" items="${courses}">
     <c:out value="${course}" /><br/>
</c:forEach>
```

You'll get it in each line separately.